# Adding effects on SVG paths

Tags: html, css, svg, styles, drawing

I'm creating a drawing application with SVG and paths. I've made a pencil, but I didn't find a way to add effects on it. I know that I can mess with the style properties of my paths, but I didn't find anything that would help to get what I'm looking for. For exemple, those effects would be nice to have :

[image]

I now that with canvas, I can add shadows and blur effects with the CanvasRenderingContext2D, but with SVG, I didn't find a sort of 'SVGRenderingContext2D'.
Can you help me with this ?
Thank you.

Comment: you could probably get something fairly close using filters.

Comment: There is a very interesting blogpost about the quest for an SVG filter that creates a pencil effect: https://heredragonsabound.blogspot.com/2020/02/creating-pencil-effect-in-svg.html

Answer (score 1):

To obtain such effects, you can use a combination of filters `feTurbulence`,`feImage`, `feDisplacementMap` changing their attributes

```html
<div class="container">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        viewBox="0 0 400 400" preserveAspectRatio="none" >  
    
 <filter id="displacementFilter">
 <feImage xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/DycTq.jpg" x="-20%" y="-20%" width="220%" height="220%" preserveAspectRatio="none"></feImage>
    <feTurbulence type="turbulence" baseFrequency="1 1"
        numOctaves="3" result="turbulence" seed="15"/>
    <feDisplacementMap in2="turbulence" in="SourceGraphic"
        scale="15" xChannelSelector="R" xChannelSelector="G" yChannelSelector="B"/>
  </filter>    




  <g filter="url(#displacementFilter)"  > 
    <path fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="22" 
 d="m26 20c65.1-1.3 140.1-1.3 190 0 14.8 0.4 14.5 19.9 0 20C158.9 40.5 108.2 39.6 25.1 40.9 10.3 41.1 8.8 20.3 26 20Z"/>  
  <line x1="10" x2="400" y1="100" y2="100"   />
 </g> 
 
</svg>

</div>
```

- By decreasing the values of `baseFrequency =" 0.2 0.1"`, we increase
  the grain size.

```html
<div class="container">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        viewBox="0 0 400 400" preserveAspectRatio="none" >  
    
 <filter id="displacementFilter">
 <feImage xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/DycTq.jpg" x="-20%" y="-20%" width="220%" height="220%" preserveAspectRatio="none"></feImage>
    <feTurbulence type="turbulence" baseFrequency="0.2 0.1"
        numOctaves="3" result="turbulence" seed="15"/>
    <feDisplacementMap in2="turbulence" in="SourceGraphic"
        scale="15" xChannelSelector="R" xChannelSelector="G" yChannelSelector="B"/>
  </filter>    




  <g filter="url(#displacementFilter)"  > 
    <path fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="22" 
 d="m26 20c65.1-1.3 140.1-1.3 190 0 14.8 0.4 14.5 19.9 0 20C158.9 40.5 108.2 39.6 25.1 40.9 10.3 41.1 8.8 20.3 26 20Z"/>  
  <line x1="10" x2="400" y1="100" y2="100"   />
 </g> 
 
</svg>

</div>
```

- By decreasing the `scale = 5` values of the`feDisplacementMap`
  filter, we decrease the wave height

```html
<div class="container">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        viewBox="0 0 400 400" preserveAspectRatio="none" >  
    
 <filter id="displacementFilter">
 <feImage xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/DycTq.jpg" x="-20%" y="-20%" width="220%" height="220%" preserveAspectRatio="none"></feImage>
    <feTurbulence type="turbulence" baseFrequency="0.2 0.1"
        numOctaves="3" result="turbulence" seed="15"/>
    <feDisplacementMap in2="turbulence" in="SourceGraphic"
        scale="5" xChannelSelector="R" xChannelSelector="G" yChannelSelector="B"/>
  </filter>    

  <g filter="url(#displacementFilter)"  > 
    <path fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="22" 
 d="m26 20c65.1-1.3 140.1-1.3 190 0 14.8 0.4 14.5 19.9 0 20C158.9 40.5 108.2 39.6 25.1 40.9 10.3 41.1 8.8 20.3 26 20Z"/>  
  <line x1="10" x2="400" y1="100" y2="100"   />
 </g> 
 
</svg>

</div>
```

- You can experiment by changing and combining filter attributes
  endlessly for interesting effects.

```html
<div class="container">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        viewBox="0 0 400 400" preserveAspectRatio="none" >  
    
 <filter id="displacementFilter">
 <feImage xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/DycTq.jpg" x="-20%" y="-20%" width="220%" height="220%" preserveAspectRatio="none"></feImage>
    <feTurbulence type="turbulence" baseFrequency="0.2 0.1"
        numOctaves="3" result="turbulence" seed="15"/>
    <feDisplacementMap in2="turbulence" in="SourceGraphic"
        scale="75" xChannelSelector="R" xChannelSelector="G" yChannelSelector="B"/>
  </filter>    

  <g filter="url(#displacementFilter)"  > 
    <path fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="22" 
 d="m26 20c65.1-1.3 140.1-1.3 190 0 14.8 0.4 14.5 19.9 0 20C158.9 40.5 108.2 39.6 25.1 40.9 10.3 41.1 8.8 20.3 26 20Z"/>  
  <line x1="10" x2="400" y1="100" y2="100"   />
 </g> 
 
</svg>

</div>
```

### Example animation

```html
<div class="container">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        viewBox="0 0 400 400" preserveAspectRatio="none" >  
    
 <filter id="displacementFilter">
 <feImage xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/DycTq.jpg" x="-20%" y="-20%" width="220%" height="220%" preserveAspectRatio="none"></feImage>
    <feTurbulence type="turbulence" baseFrequency="0.2 0.1"
        numOctaves="3" result="turbulence" seed="15"/>
    <feDisplacementMap in2="turbulence" in="SourceGraphic"
        scale="5" xChannelSelector="R" xChannelSelector="G" yChannelSelector="B"/>
  </filter>    

  <g filter="url(#displacementFilter)"  > 
    <path stroke-dasharray="450" stroke-dashoffset="450" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="22" 
 d="m26 20c65.1-1.3 140.1-1.3 190 0 14.8 0.4 14.5 19.9 0 20C158.9 40.5 108.2 39.6 25.1 40.9 10.3 41.1 8.8 20.3 26 20Z">
<animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" values="450;0" dur="4s" fill="freeze" />
 </path>
  <line x1="10" x2="400" y1="100" y2="100"   />
 </g> 
 
</svg>

</div>
```

Comment: @hichamcheniti If the answer was useful to you, please remember to mark it as a solution.